# VS Code how to open a window does not install any extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Suppose I cloned a Vue repository, but I may not need many other unneeded extensions. I want to use a new window that does not have the extension installed.

If I choose to disable all installed extensions, then my other working workspace extensions will also be disabled, which will be particularly bad at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove all extensions for that one window, type `code --disable-extensions`. If you want to remove a specific one, `code --disable-extension id.extension-name`. For example, `code --disable-extension belfz.search-crates-io` to disable the search crates.io extension for that window.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this command. It is indeed the function I want. I used to think it would disable the extensions in all my projects, so I didn't dare to try it. Now it seems that it is only temporarily disabled. My worries are superfluous. ,awesome.